# Why don't the Shutter Speed, Exposure Time, Lens Aperture, and F-Number metadata values from my camera make sense?

Tags: exposure, aperture, metadata, shutter-speed, f-stop

I was just looking at some digital image properties, and it did not seem to make sense.

```
Shutter Speed: 1/16 sec.
Exposure Time: 1/11 sec.
Lens Aperture: F/1
F-Number: 2.8
```

I would have thought that shutter speed would be equivalent to exposure time and lens aperture to f-number. What am I missing?

Comment: What camera model was used?

Comment: Camera is Moultrie MFH-DGS-M80.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is quite common in EXIF data but the values are usually closer. It is possible the EXIF data for that photo is telling us a lens with a maximum aperture of f/1.0 was used at f/2.8 and the shutter speed was set to 1/16 and that resulted in an actual exposure time of 1/11.

Here is an example where the shutter speed and aperture selected were 1/500 and f/1.8 but the actual shutter speed value and aperture value were 1/512 and f/1.76

[image]